# A nice pattern about Goldbach conjecture in French Wikipedia

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

In the following link: https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjecture_de_Goldbach, one can see a nice pattern of pink and blue lines coming from each prime number, the intersection points thereof are circled. Call those circles on the pink line emanating from $p$ "the Goldbach $p$-dots". It is quite easy to figure out that there are $\pi(p)-1$ such $p$-dots, corresponding to the even numbers $2n$ between $p+3$ and $2p$ such that $2n-p$ is prime, hence to the primes between $3$ and $p$. Now if we sum up the number of $p$-dots for consecutive values of $p$ up to $x$, we get a lower bound for the sum of Goldbach decompositions of the even numbers not exceeding $2x$.

That is:

$$\sum_{2<p\leq  x/2}\left(\pi(p)-1\right)\leq\sum_{n\leq x}G(2n)\leq\sum_{2<p<x}\left(\pi(p)-1)\right)$$.

While it doesn't prove Goldbach's conjecture by itself, it gives both a lower and an upper bound for the average growth rate of $G(2n)$, that is, the number of representations of $2n$ as the sum of two primes.

Would this and known bounds for $\pi(x)$ allow to prove that Goldbach's conjecture implies the extended Goldbach's conjecture derived semiheuristically by Hardy and Littlewood in 1923?

Edit: note that the LHS in the double inequality above is asymptotically equal to $\frac{\pi(x/2)^2}{2}\sim\frac{x^2}{8\log^{2}x}$ and thus $\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}G(2n)\gtrsim\frac{x}{8\log^{2}x}$ so that the average value $\tilde{G}(2n)$ of $G(2n)$ fulfills $\tilde{G}(2n)\asymp\frac{n}{\log^{2}n}$.

Comment: What is the explicit statement of extended Goldbach by Hardy and Littlewood?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture : $G(2n)\sim 2C_{2}\prod_{p>2}\frac{p-1}{p-2}\frac{2n}{\log^{2}2n}$, where $C_{2}=0.66016...$ is the twin prime constant.